# Impossible captcha

Tags: support

I was reading some questions/answers on the site, and then I ended on a "Human verification" page, with a captcha (recaptcha). While the captchas were easily readable, I had to try around 30 times before going through... Here are a few screenshots to support my saying (all those captcha failed) :

[image: Captcha 1]
[image: Captcha 2]
[image: Captcha 3]
[image: Captcha 4]
[image: Captcha 5]
[image: Captcha 6]

Comment: What browser are you using? On what operating system? Are you using HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: Are you using Tor or another proxy?

Comment: Firefox, on Windows 7. I can give you the exact version tomorrow. I'm not using Tor, but yes I am behind a corporate proxy. How can I know wether I'm using HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: Firefox version :  26.0

Comment: think the first one is "opapple peciplni".  The reasoning "ln" is the l extends above the start on the line from the "n"

Comment: And in the second one, the second word starts with a "p" (not with an "r"). I hate those captchas as well (though I see their reason) – and usually "solve" them by simply logging in :) // Apart from that: What was your question?

Comment: I agree about the 1st captcha, but I disagree about the 2nd, I see an 'r' pretty clear